# Why does a Junit integration test for repository fail with Referential integrity constraint violation when the code work fine in the app live

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have a really weird problem, we have a junit integration test which test the repository class that fail after adding a new field that come from another table.
However when testing the code live everything is fine.
We are trying to figure out why.

We have a Post entity that now have a new latestPostVersion field

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
@Setter
public class Post
    extends Serializable
{
    private long id;
    private int version;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    //.. more field
    
    private PostHistory lastestPostVersion;
    
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    
    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    public int getVersion()
    {
        return version;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "VERSION", referencedColumnName = "VERSION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public PostHistory getLatestPostVersion()
    {
        return latestPostVersion;
    }

    //... 
}
```

This latestPostVersion is a object containing some info we need about the last Post

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST_HISTORY")
@Setter
public class Post
    extends Serializable
{


    private long id;
    private int version;
    private String createBy;
    private Instant createDate;
    private String title;


    
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    
    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    public int getVersion()
    {
        return version;
    }

     //... more mapping

}
```

This work fine in our service class, which handle the creation of the Post and then the history.

```
private ClientPost savePost(ClientPost post, String updatedBy){

        Post dbPost = convertToDbModel(post);

        Post persistedPost =
            postRepository.saveAndFlush(post);

        PostHistory persistedPostHistory =
            postHistoryRepository.saveAndFlush(
                new PostHistory(persistedPost, updatedBy));
                
        return convertToApiModel(persistedPost, persistedPostHistory);
}
```

However when testing the repository in a Junit test it fail but only on the find all, findById is fine, eventhough the post is built the same way.

```
@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
@DataJpaTest(showSql = false)
class PostRepositoryTest
{
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repository;

    @BeforeEach
    void init()
    {
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle("Title");
        // ... fill post
        post.setPostHistory(null);
        
        entityManager.persist(post);
    }
    
    @Test
    void findAll_existingPosts_returnsAllPost()
    {
        List<Post> posts = repository.findAll();
        assertEquals(1, posts.size());
    }
}
```

The test give this error

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK7ITU2SCAYHBAV3TA9DU94CDA3: PUBLIC.POST FOREIGN KEY(ID, VERSION) REFERENCES PUBLIC.POST_HISTORY(ID, VERSION) (CAST(1902 AS BIGINT), 0)"; SQL statement:
insert into post (version, ...,  id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-214]
```

I've found a way to make both the code and the test work if we change getLastestPostVersion() to be a OneToMany and to return a Set.

However, I would like understand why it was working with the code but not the test and if possible keep the code the way it is and make the test pass elegantly.

EDIT:
Here a quick run down of the table (the field that matter)

POST Table

```
ID bigInt not null PrimaryKey
TITLE varchar not null
BODY varchar default null
POST_HISTORY_ID bigInt key: MULTIPLE default null
POST_HISTORY_VERSION bigInt default null

POST_FK_POST_HISTORY owner POST refTable POST_HISTORY refObject PRIMARY
```

POST_HISTORY table

```
ID bigInt not null PrimaryKey
VERSION bigInt not null PrimaryKey
TITLE varchar not null
USER varchar not null
TIMESTAMP datetime not null
```

Comment: There is a log missing from your question - how have you setup the databases? Why is it complaining about a foreign key :PUBLIC.POST FOREIGN KEY(ID, VERSION) REFERENCES PUBLIC.POST_HISTORY(ID, VERSION) (CAST(1902 AS BIGINT), 0) ? Did you maybe set it up so that there is a foreign key from POST to your postHistory table based on the version/id values? How are you setting the Post id value, and how are you cleaning up Posts created in your init and tests, and any PostHistory that might be created from those tests? And for your Post_history entry - you might have cut and paste it wrong

Comment: I suspect you are using JPA to create your tables, and since you've created a mapping from Post->PostHistory, it creates a fk constraint there too. it won't do that for a 1:M as it knows the other side is the foreign key. Note that this mapping is difficult to work with JPA, as the version value will get updated on each modification, but the entity reference to PostHistory will not - meaning you can never effectively cache this entity as the reference will be stale after every modification. I don't quite understand how you are putting in the 'latest' version value either; it'll always be null

Comment: Looks like your test db enforces foreign key constraints while your prod db does not.

Comment: id you maybe set it up so that there is a foreign key from POST to your postHistory table based on the version/id values?  

POST_HISTORY doesn't have any foreign key, However POST have a foreign key to POST_HISTORY on the id and version. 
The only constraint on POST is it primary key.

Comment: You ARE using JPA to generate your DDL (in test), and it is setting that fk because you have set a relationship from Post->PostHistory on those columns -which are wrong as mentioned. You will need to look at the generated DDL to explain it, but your mappings are not accurate. Technically, PostHistory should reference Post, and Post would have multiple PostHistories based on the ID value. Latest history though will NEVER work, as the current post won't have a history row associated to it - it gets incremented after every change, and there cannot be a row for that version hence the exception.

Comment: The problem was H2 generating the FK constraint that don't exist in the original db. there 3 way of fixing this, one is using onetomany instead of onetoone 2-reversing the mapping so postHistory does it and 3- using a hack that remove the constraint from h2 when running the test.